# Making the Raspberry Pi Pico a part of my PCB

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I am using Altium Designer 21.9. I would like to make a MOSFET-based DC machine controller circuit, which takes PWM from a Rasberry Pi Pico. Later I want to apply a control algorithm.

I would like to put the RPi Pico on top of my PCB Board.  I have downloaded the design from the Rasberry website. How should I add or draw it in the schematic so that I can solder pins to it and put it on top of my circuit board (PCB) like an IC?

1. I need to connect my encoder with it.
2. I have made a 3.3 V input for MCU in my circuit drawing.
3. The output PINs from two PWM pins on the RPi Pico go to my gate drivers.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this question is really "How do you create a package symbol and footprint in Altium?", or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps, I am describing it poorly. I know the process of the pacage and footprint for a component. Now, how should one approach to draw a RPI-PICO in another  Schematic. do i need to pin diagram in my Schmatic? and later i get holes for perspective connection. I don't want draw the whole and solder all components of PICO circuit. I want put the Whole board on top my PCB board.

Comment: Just view the Pi-Pico as any other component. The fact that it's a PCB with soldered components rather than a silicon die covered in a plastic cover doesn't make any real difference in drawing the schematic or PCB. Create a schematics symbol with the pins present on the Pi-Pico, then draw a PCB footrprint matching the Pi-Pico and off you go.

Comment: The Pi Pico appears to be equivalent to a standard DIP-40 package with a few extra pins on the end for debug and a USB port (that won't land on your PCB anyway).  Why not use a standard DIP 40 footprint?

Comment: @Theodore the actual Pi Pico footprint has keep-out areas for test points and for the pins of the USB connector (as well as drill holes to match those, but I've found that the pins do not protrude, so I removed the drill holes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've downloaded the wrong file. You don't want the RPi Pico design file (that's for making one yourself), you want a RPi Pico footprint and symbol (to integrate into your board).

You have these options:

- find a RPi Pico footprint and symbol library for Altium
- convert one that's not for Altium (I know there is one for KiCAD)
- make your own from the datasheet drawings.

Comment: Thanks very much, I found one for altium, and added to my existing Library. 
Unfotunately, i still have some confusions about TP1-TP6 pins of PICO and connecting it to my board.
1) this is a symbol and footprint if i want to use PICO as SMD component, is it okay to just add pins and use it on my board. 
2) also, For near USB there is TP1-TP6, do i need to connect them with my board, if so is it actually possible to do it as THT?   
3) I can see in pico datasheet TP1 is ground, is it a good idea to connect ground from my circuitry to this?

Comment: @rafi You only need to connect the ground pins, power pins, and the pins you actually want to use. Everything else (including TP1-TP6) can be left unconnected. As for SMD vs THT, for sure you can modify the footprint.

Comment: Also good to think whether you're powering your board via the pico, or the other way around, and what happens if you have the USB cable connected vs. disconnected: is there a risk you could backpower the computer? etc.